# Terminology: What is the forcible removal of a resource assigned to a process called?

Tags: resources, operating-system, terminology

What is the forcible (non-voluntary) removal of a resource assigned to a process called?

I can't seem to remember the name describing this.  I've tried searching and haven't come up with the key term either.

Answer (score 1):

Revocation? 
Invalidation?
Yoink?

Pretty sure it's "yoink".

Answer (score 1):

In general, resource revocation.  Specifically to resources managed via handles, handle invalidation.

Answer (score 0):

I know with locks it is called "breaking the lock". I don't know of a general term applicable to every kind of resource. I suppose I'd call it "revoking the resource" if I really had to come up with one.